# Prove trichotomy of order WITHOUT induction?

Tags: induction, natural-numbers, peano-axioms

> **Claim.** If $x,y \in \mathbb N$, then at least one of these is true: (a) $x>y$; (b) $x=y$; or (c) $x<y$.

It seems that the usual proof of this claim uses induction. Is it possible to prove this without induction? (Or is perhaps this claim false without the axiom of induction?)

Comment: Your Question would be more meaningful if it spelled out what assumptions are left after omitting induction, and how the relations $\lt,=,\gt $ are accordingly defined.

Comment: You really need to provide the formal definitions of $<$ and $>$ in order to get a proper answer to this. Depending on that, counterexamples may or may not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we drop the induction axiom (but keep the other four Peano axioms), then we could have $$\mathbb N = \{0,\bigstar_0,1,\bigstar_1,2,\bigstar_2,\dots \}.$$

And now $0 \nless \bigstar_0$ , $0\neq \bigstar_0$, and $0 \ngtr \bigstar_0$.